# How do I enter Setup and get into Ubuntu Core command line in a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I successfully installed the Ubuntu Core in a Raspberry Pi 3. The system starts, I completed setup and now when I start the system, states firstly "No ethernet found", load all libraries and it goes straight to a screen like this:

Ubuntu Core 16 on IP

Host key fingerprints
RSA SHA256: ABCD
DSA SHA256: ABCD
ECDSA SHA256: ABCD
ED25519 SHA256: ABCD

To login:
ssh my_user@192.168.1.1

Obviously I am not being able to ssh into the device, I get the error: "ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.1 port 22: Connection timed out". So, I'd like to get help on two issues:

1. How do I enter Ubuntu Core Setup again to fix ethernet ?
2. How do I access the Ubuntu Core command line?

Comment: The error message `ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.1 port 22: Connection timed out` says you don't have `sshd` running on the device.

Comment: I understand, but I am not being able to access command line to start the `sshd` service. It's a fresh installation.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about my previous ignorance. I solved both issues. To answer question 1 I flashed the image again with Etcher in Raspberry Pi after formatting the SD Card. Then I SSH'd into Ubuntu Core with proper id_rsa key, passphrase and password.

Here is a guide I developed after succeeding:

[Github Link](https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/tree/master/Raspberry%20Pi3%20IoT-Project)

Comment: sorry, the link isn't active any more.

Comment: I just fixed the link. Thanks for noticing.